# Opalang and issue with the Server.start() arguments

Tags: opa

so this Opa thing is picking up.
Im starting a Server like this:

```
    function resource request_dispatch(Uri.relative p_url,
                                       p_log_fun) {
            //type Uri.relative = {list(string) path, list((string,string)) query }
            match (p_url) {
                case {path: [] ... }              : get_standard_page(p_log_fun);
                case {path: ["_rest_" | path] ...}: api_request_handler(path,p_log_fun);
                case {~path ...}                  : Resource.page("Regular",<div>standard page</div>);
            }
        }     
function start_server(p_log_fun) {
            function resource dispatch_handler_fun(Uri.relative p_url) {
                request_dispatch(p_url,p_log_fun)
            }
            Server.start(Server.http,
                         { title   : "Hello, world",
                           dispatch:dispatch_handler_fun})
        }
```

however Im getting:

> Error: File "src/posts_viewer.opa", line 71, characters 3-150,
>   (71:3-74:42 | 2466-2613)
>   Type Conflict
>   (72:10-74:41)       {dispatch: (Uri.relative -> resource); title: string } /
>                         'c.a
>   (71:3-71:8)         Server.handler
>        The second argument of function should be of type
>          { dispatch: (Uri.relative -> resource); title: string } / 
>    'c.a
>   instead of
>   Server.handler

so its clearly dispatch_handler_fun is not of the correct type signature.
in the API docs I can see that Server.handler in a variant
http://doc.opalang.org/type/stdlib.core.web.server/Server/handler

is it clear to anyone why dispatch_handler_fun is not appropriate here?
ps. sorry for the bad code formating :)

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `{title, dispatch}` in variant type `Server.handler`, only `{string title, 
(→ xhtml) page}` and `{ (Uri.relative → resource) dispatch }` (no title field).

The reason title is connected to `page` and not to `dispatch` is the `page` returns only `xhtml` body without the HTML header. The server need some additional data as the title of the page. The `dispatch` function you use returns the resource which has some extra data attached and there is no need to give it to the server twice. You already used the function `Resource.page()` in your example, which takes the title as the first parameter.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer. :) -- "The dispatch function you use returns the resource which has some extra data attached and there is no need to give it to the server twice." -- what would you recommend I use here? since 'dispatch' is expected to be of type "(Uri.relative -> resource)" (aka the function should return a resource, as do my functions).

Comment: so I removed the 'title' member from Server.start(), since you suggested that the resources created by dispatch_handler_fun() have their own title. now the app compiles with no type errors :)